# Is there a way to override the text displayed by the autoclass directive reST?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs, autodoc

I created the documentation using the autoclass directive in reST, and it generates a header for the class like this:

[image: Read the Docs Example]

What I want, however, is for it to not say `dataframe.DataFrame` but instead `EzPyZ.DataFrame` (or really any manual override of that default text). This is the code I used:

```
.. autoclass:: dataframe.DataFrame
```

Comment: I'm confused. If you want it to say **EzPyZ.DataFrame** in the output, why don't you use `.. autoclass:: EzPyZ.DataFrame`?

Comment: @mzjn thank you. I am just a moron.

Comment: @EthanGuthrie welcome to MoronOverflow, where newbies are always welcome. 

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as I expected. I am a moron. As @mzjn pointed out, all I had to do was simply put:

```
.. autoclass: EzPyZ.DataFrame
```

The autodocs will fill in the path however you specify, so long as it is a valid path to the class. In my case (see directory structure below), the `Column` class can be accessed by using either `EzPyZ.column.Column`, `column.Column` (because the autodoc implicitly imports the targe package for documentation), or (as I wanted) `EzPyZ.Column`.

```
  EzPyZ
    └── EzPyZ
          ├── __init__.py
          ├── column.py      # Contains Column class.
          ├── dataframe.py   # Contains DataFrame class.
          └── tools
                ├── __init__.py
                └── read_files.py    # Contains some extra functions.
```